# Executing PHP code from HTML file loaded by PHP

Tags: php, html

I created a little DIV in HTML which gets filled by a main_login.php
main_login.php loads the homepage with member content on the side if there is a session started
If there is no session started, the main_login.php file loads the homepage with loginfields.html on the side

- main_login.php: http://pastebin.com/vkhccGSB
- loginfields.html: http://pastebin.com/fDJjTjsf

Now whenever loginfields.html is loaded, the button on that page doesnt execute whenever I press it. When I open the localhost/loginfields.html it works like a charm.

What is preventing the login_check.php to load?

Comment: codes are on pastebin. Links are in the opening post

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a wild guess here, and say that you're loading in `main_login.php` via AJAX and using `innerHTML` (or jQuery's `html()`) to put it into the page. I'm also guessing that your button is powered by a `<script>` tag.

`<script>` tags loaded with `innerHTML` are *not* executed. You have to either load it in as an external script (even then I'm not sure if `innerHTML` will load it in), or use proper DOM functions to append the script to the page, or separate the HTML and JavaScript from the response and run the JS through `eval`.

Comment: yes I am using innerHTML via Ajax but im not using script tags. I used a form.

Comment: Have you ran the main_login.php alone to check it read the html file correctly?

Comment: Nothing happening. I opened the console on Opera, Firefox and Chrome. Chrome seems to let me login btw, which is odd..

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to load loginfields.php into the page, you could just use `include('loginfields.php')` instead of your fopen() function.

Comment: Because he wants to get the text and insert it to a div using innerHTML, its an ajax call.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  Sorry about that.